# How to include automation framework jar file dependency in my maven pom.xml?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, maven, external-dependencies, test-configration

I want to include one .jar file which has classes of my core automation framework. I created a "lib" folder in my selenium project and then gave its path in the pom.xml dependency. This Jar file of framework is not a runnable jar. I exported the framework project as a jar and want to use its classes in my project.

However, im not able to use any class/method from that jar(framework) in my test scripts. Am i doing something wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in your pom.xml:

```
<url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
```

to:

```
<url>${project.basedir}/lib</url>
```

Do confirm is it works.

Comment: NO, this does not work. I cant use my classes from jar. Not sure what's the issue? :/

Comment: Do i need to use something like Maven assembly plugin or else. I dont want to use classes directly in a package, i want to just use a .jar file.

Comment: You mean for using classes from a Jar file included in the configure build path?

Comment: Yes. Do i need to add the jar to the build path or only in pom.xml?

Comment: I have added jar in the build path as well. Still project doesnt recognise the classes inside the jar file. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you give an example of where exactly you are facing issue. Usually, if you add the JAR to build path you should be able to use the classes. You might need to create an object of that class to access the methods within it, for example, with Selenium you have to create an object of WebDriver; WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); and then you can do driver.get() and driver.findElement(); and so on.

Comment: If you add the JAR to build path, you should need to add it to POM XML again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very crucial part of automation, especially for parent-child project structure in POM-based automation. I also faced a similar issue when I worked on a project related to [data quality testing](https://blog.qasource.com/implement-a-qa-process-for-your-data). We have created a core framework that contains all the actions, drivers, utilities, etc. The purpose was to use this core framework in the automation of multiple projects. When I tried to use this core framework in the automation of the core project, I used the below steps to resolve that.

Let's consider, your Parent project's POM looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Run **mvn clean install** in the command prompt on the parent project directory. This will create a jar file of your parent project and place it in the .m2 repository of your user's folder in C drive.

Next Step, open the child's project POM file and add the above jar file as a dependency in it as mentioned below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
   <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, you will be able to use all the classes of the parent project in the child project. Hope this information is helpful for you. Thanks!!!!!